# How to call another class method that includes the other method?

Tags: python

I have a class below:

```py
    class Test:
        def alpha(self):
            a = 5
            return a
    
        def bravo(self):
            alp = self.alpha()
            c = 2
            solution = alp + c
            print(solution)
            return solution
```

and I am trying to write a new class that calls Test.bravo(),
but having an error due to Test.alpha inside of it.

How can I write a new class? below is what I did:

```py
    class Test2:
        def charlie(self):
            call_bravo = Test.bravo(self)
            print(call_bravo)

    def main():
        tst = Test()
        tst.bravo()
    
        tst2 = Test2()
        tst2.charlie()

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

Comment: Do you want to do `call_bravo = Test().bravo()`? Or you want to pass `Test2` as an argument of `Test.bravo` (which is what you are doing right now)

Answer (score 1):

The solution below works correctly.

```
class Test:

    def alpha(self):
        a = 5
        return a

    def bravo(self):
        alp = self.alpha()
        c = 2
        solution = alp + c
        print(solution)


class Test2:
    def charlie(self):
        call_bravo = Test()
        res = call_bravo.bravo()
        print(res)

def main():
    tst = Test()
    tst.bravo()

    tst2 = Test2()
    tst2.charlie()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

I expect that your error is because you're trying to invoke a method of class `Test` to operate on an object of `Test2`.

```
tst2.Charlie() invokes
Test.bravo(tst2), which invokes
tst2.alpha()
```

Your problem is that there *is* no such routine: the only `alpha` in your design is a method of Test; there is no `alpha` method for `Test2`.

In short, you have a fatal design error.  Sort out what functionality you want in each class.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Do you mean I need to declare alpha in Test2 as well?

Comment: I don't know what you need: you haven't told us what application problem you're trying to solve.  It appears that you have improperly designed your classes and methods.